# Excel VBA add value to entire column that matches a specific header

Tags: excel, vba

So i need to add 2021 to the Assessment year column in my worksheet but the range keeps breaking

LastRow is returning the correct value but i cant manage to figure out why range isnt working

```
   Sub AutoFill()

   Dim rFind As Range
   Dim ColumnLetter As Variant
   Dim ColumnNumber As Variant
   Dim LastRow As Variant
   Dim Fill As Range

   With Range("A1:P1")
   Set rFind = .Find(What:="AssessmentYear", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False) 
   If Not rFind Is Nothing Then 
   ColumnNumber = rFind.Column
   ColumnLetter = Split(Cells(1, ColumnNumber).Address, "$")(1)
   LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
   MsgBox ColumnLetter 
   MsgBox LastRow  
   Cells(LastRow, ColumnNumber).Value = "Here"
   Range("ColumnLetter & 2 : ColumnLetter & LastRow").Value = "2021"

       End If
   End With
   End Sub
```

I keep getting a method global failed error

Comment: I need it to be able to be flexible as the column and the last row wont ever be the same as the next sheet

Answer (score 1):

The issue is VBA sees "ColumnLetter & 2 : ColumnLetter & LastRow" as a string and is not actually using the variables ColumnLetter or LastRow. Just change it to the below and it should work fine.

```
Range(ColumnLetter & "2 : " & ColumnLetter & LastRow).Value = "2021"
```

Comment: Cant thank you enough. Literally the smallest change and it works

Answer (score 0):

### Auto Fill Data Column

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub AutoFillDataColumn()

    Const hAddress As String = "A1:P1"
    Const hTitle As String = "AssessmentYear"
    Const cValue As Variant = 2021
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim hrg As Range: Set hrg = ws.Range(hAddress)
    
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = RefDataColumnByHeader(hrg, hTitle)
    If rg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    rg.Value = cValue

End Sub

Function RefDataColumnByHeader( _
    ByVal HeaderRange As Range, _
    ByVal HeaderTitle As String) _
As Range
    
    If HeaderRange Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    
    Dim hCell As Range
    With HeaderRange
        Set hCell = .Find(HeaderTitle, .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count), _
            xlFormulas, xlWhole, xlByRows)
        If hCell Is Nothing Then Exit Function
        If hCell.Row = .Worksheet.Rows.Count Then Exit Function
        Debug.Print "Header Cell Address:      " & hCell.Address(0, 0)
    End With
    
    Dim hrrg As Range
    Set hrrg = Intersect(HeaderRange, hCell.EntireRow)
    Debug.Print "Header Row Range Address: " & hrrg.Address(0, 0)
    
    With hrrg
        
        Dim lcrg As Range
        Set lcrg = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row).Offset(1)
        Debug.Print "Last Cell Range Address:  " & lcrg.Address(0, 0)
        
        Dim lCell As Range
        Set lCell = lcrg.Find("*", , xlFormulas, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
        If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Function
        Debug.Print "Last Cell Address:        " & lCell.Address(0, 0)
           
        Set RefDataColumnByHeader = hCell.Resize(lCell.Row - .Row).Offset(1)
        Debug.Print "Data Column Address:      " _
            & RefDataColumnByHeader.Address(0, 0)
        
    End With

End Function
```